How to keep TS ambient declarations while adding a custom element to Preact's JSX types?
There's a bit of information out there, but unfortunately, none of the examples for ambient modules cover how to augment JSX specifically, which works a bit differently.
I need both of these types to work, and no combination I've come across yet will support this.
import preact from 'preact';

declare module '*.module.css' {
    const mapping: Record<string, string>;
    export default mapping;
}

declare module "preact" {
    namespace JSX {
        interface IntrinsicElements {
            "my-custom-el": CustomElProps;
        }
    }
}

interface CustomElProps extends preact.JSX.HTMLAttributes<HTMLElement> {
    enabled: boolean;
}

The top level import breaks the *.module.css, but you can't move that import into the declare module 'preact' block without breaking JSX types.
